# How to select variables from dataframe inside other recursive dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

> str(data_raw)
>   'data.frame':   20 obs. of  18 variables:

$ id            : chr  "2306173214621953247_176548637" "2304792897512042631_176548637" "2298783867773662543_176548637" "2249480367030200759_176548637" ...

$ user          :'data.frame': 20 obs. of  4 variables:

..$ id             : chr  "176548637" "176548637" "176548637" "176548637" ...

..$ full_name      : chr  "Carlos Costa" "Carlos Costa" "Carlos Costa" "Carlos Costa" ...

But when I try to get the **user$id** variable, it shows the error:

> data_raw<- data_raw %>%
>       select(id,user.id)

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x The column `user.id` doesn't exist.

I also tried this way:

> data_raw<- data_raw %>%
>   +     select(id,user$id)
>   Error: object 'user' not found

I know that the **user** variable is a dataframe, but how do I get information from a dataframe within another dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the structure to help. The dataframe has only 1 line.

> dput(head(data_raw, 2))

```
    structure(list(id = "2306173214621953247_176548637", user = structure(list(
    id = "176548637", full_name = "Carlos Costa", profile_picture = "link.com", 
    username = "carlosocosta"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    images = structure(list(thumbnail = structure(list(width = 150L, height = 150L, url = "link.com"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
        low_resolution = structure(list(width = 320L, height = 320L, 
            url = "link.com"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
        standard_resolution = structure(list(width = 640L, height = 640L, 
            url = "link.com"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    created_time = "1589137292", caption = structure(list(id = "18105905566138276", 
        text = "Não basta ser mãe! Tem que aprender a jogar Fortnite! Feliz dia das mães! #maedemenino", 
        created_time = "1589137292", from = structure(list(id = "176548637", 
            full_name = "Carlos Costa", profile_picture = "link.com", 
            username = "carlosocosta"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    user_has_liked = FALSE, likes = structure(list(count = 69L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    tags = list("maedemenino"), filter = "Normal", comments = structure(list(
        count = 3L), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), type = "image", 
    link = "link.com", location = structure(list(
        latitude = NA_real_, longitude = NA_real_, name = NA_character_, 
        id = NA_integer_), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    attribution = NA, users_in_photo = list(structure(list(user = structure(list(
        username = "vivicosta_oficial"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        position = structure(list(x = 0.2210144928, y = 0.5857487923), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    carousel_media = list(NULL), videos = structure(list(standard_resolution = structure(list(
        width = NA_integer_, height = NA_integer_, url = NA_character_, 
        id = NA_character_), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
        low_resolution = structure(list(width = NA_integer_, 
            height = NA_integer_, url = NA_character_, id = NA_character_), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
        low_bandwidth = structure(list(width = NA_integer_, height = NA_integer_, 
            url = NA_character_, id = NA_character_), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    video_views = NA_integer_), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you should not add this as an answer but include it in your question instead by editing it. Also the `dput`still doesn't work for me, it is incomplete. Does it work for you? Can you copy and paste it into R?

Answer (score 0):

Since we have a dataframe inside a dataframe, make it a single dataframe using `do.call` +`cbind` and then subset the columns needed.

```
do.call(cbind, data_raw)[c('id', 'user.id')]

#                             id   user.id
#1 2306173214621953247_176548637 176548637
#2 2304792897512042631_176548637 176548637
```

Or with `dplyr::select`

```
library(dplyr)
do.call(cbind, data_raw) %>% select(id, user.id)
```

**data**

Tested on this data :

```
data_raw <- data.frame(id = c('2306173214621953247_176548637',
                              '2304792897512042631_176548637'))
user <- data.frame(id = c('176548637', '176548637'), full_name = c('a', 'b'))     
data_raw$user <- user

str(data_raw)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ id  : chr  "2306173214621953247_176548637" "2304792897512042631_176548637"
# $ user:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  ..$ id       : chr  "176548637" "176548637"
#  ..$ full_name: chr  "a" "b"
```

Comment: > do.call(cbind, data_raw)[c('id', 'user.id')]
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0, 2, 3, 5
> do.call(cbind, data_raw) %>% select(id, user.id)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0, 2, 3, 5

Comment: > dput(data_raw)
structure(list(id = c("2306173214621953247_176548637", "2304792897512042631_176548637", 
"2298783867773662543_176548637"), user = structure(list(id = c("176548637", "176548637", "176548637"), full_name = c("Carlos Costa", "Carlos Costa", 
"Carlos Costa")                                 (each object has 20 observations, but I removed this post so it doesn't get big)

Comment: @CarlosDeOliveiraCosta but this data is incomplete. It doesn't run. Update your question with `dput(head(raw_data, 2))`.

Comment: can you review the simplified version that I put above, please

Comment: @CarlosDeOliveiraCosta yes, `dput` works now. Which are the column names that you want in the final dataframe.